# How to create looping email notifications with conditions

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, email

I need to create a repeating workflow email notification (every 14 days) to users who add items to the list.
It needs to stop repeating once the current item 'end date' in the past or the item is cancelled. At that time the workflow should end on that list item.

I have written a SPD workflow which seems logical to me. What do I need to change please to make this work?

[image]

Cheers - Scott

Revised WorkFlow

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can u try to add a pause for 14 days before the loop 1 and add a pause for 14 days in the if condition block, under the email statement. The last pause which is already given in the workflow should be removed. Let me know if it works. And make sure to tick in the workflow start option **Item Created**.

let me know if it works o not. Thanks.

Comment: Is the revised workflow I added to my original post what you meant Tahmidul?

Comment: Just put the 2nd pause statement after the email statement. As like: 
.

`Email Current Item:Created By
then Pause for 14 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes`

Comment: Thanks Thamidul - I've tested it now on a 10 min loop and it works!